# error: no matching function for call to 'copy'

Tags: c++

```
wxString P::getParentPath(const wxString &ss){
    wxString dst;
    for(wxString::const_iterator it=ss.end();it!=ss.begin();it--)
        if(*it=='\\'){
            std::copy(ss.begin(),ss.end()-it,dst.begin());
            break;
        }
    return s;
}


error: no matching function for call to 'copy(wxString::const_iterator, wxString::const_iterator::difference_type, wxString::iterator)'|
```

I'm trying to copy a part of string to another string, I get this error while trying.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `s.end()-it` is a number not an iterator. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Getting parent directory path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy everything from the beginning of the string up to but excluding the final `\`, then `it` is pointing exactly where you want it, just after the last character to be copied.

So you just need

```
std::copy(ss.begin(), it, <something>);
```

But `<something>` cannot be `dst.begin()`, because `dst` is empty. You might be able to use `back_inserter(dst)`, but I don't think that will work with a `wxString`.

I suspect you're better off using the `SubString` function in `wxString`.